# Prevent linux child process to terminate when parent process terminates

Tags: java

I need to keep a child process running after the parent process terminate.

At my Ubuntu 18 (System D) I created a service to run my **java** application as a service.

To start it, I use:

```
systemctl start my-service
```

This is `my-service` service unit definition:

```
[Unit]
Description=Java Linux Service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/root
ExecStart=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /root/my-service.jar
RestartForceExitStatus=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Inside this `my-service` java application I launch a **child process** (another java application) and I need to keep it running **after** the `my-service` stops.

The problem is that, when I run the `systemctl stop my-service` the child process is **terminated** too.

I tried to launch the child process with the `nohup` command, but without success, my java code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("houp java -jar child.jar");
```

Someone can provide an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you share the Java portion of the code?

Comment: that's not system v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81973/systemd-keep-forked-process-alive-when-service-is-stopped) .

I just changed my service description unit, adding `KillMode=process` like this :

```
[Unit]
Description=Java Linux Service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/root
ExecStart=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /root/linux-service.jar
RestartForceExitStatus=2
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```